# Crawling Issue with Apache Nutch 1.12

Tags: apache, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to crawling. I was using https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3._Crawl_your_first_website
to perform crawling with nutch 1.12. I did the setup using Cygwin on windows.

The "bin/nutch" command is running fine but to crawl i did the following changes -

1. This is my conf/nutch-site.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>http.agent.name</name>
  <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

2. This is the content of my urls/seed.txt file that I created

   https://www.drugs.com/

Now when I run the following command`bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls`
I get the nullPointerException as shown below

```
MithL@DESKTOP-K3INBH0 /home/apache-nutch-1.12
$ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
Injector: starting at 2017-02-21 14:03:51
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:849)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createNewFile(FileSystem.java:1149)
        at org.apache.nutch.util.LockUtil.createLockFile(LockUtil.java:58)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:357)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:441)
```

Please suggest what I should do. Thank you

**!UPDATE!**

I added hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar to apache-nutch-1.12/lib folder and also set the HADOOP_HOME environment variable to `C:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe`

Now it gives a UnsupportedOperationException as shown below

```
$ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
Injector: starting at 2017-02-21 21:37:32
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:347)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:441)
```

Please suggest what I should do. Thank you

Comment: Try debugging and see if you can find anything. Its possible to remote debug nutch. https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse

Comment: I'm using Nutch 2.x and it doesn't work in windows. I have installed Ubuntu on Oracle Virtual Box to work with Nutch. Not sure if same is the case with 1.x series.

Comment: see your logs for more details