# Cygwin packages for nutch 1.12

Tags: hadoop, solr, cygwin, web-crawler, nutch

I can't seem to run nutch 1.12 on windows in Cygwin [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362557/crawling-issue-with-apache-nutch-1-12)

After researching alot i think the reason is unavailability of some Cygwin packages (*I had gone with the **default** download*).

Can someone please let me know all the Cygwin packages that are required for nutch 1.12 (*full package install on Cygwin is 70+ GB*)